# Checkbox not display element when checked in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am working in meteor and am trying to display a block of code when a checkbox is checked. I am new to JS and jquery, but I have research different ways of writing the JS. This is what I came up with:

```
<div class="recipient">
      <div class="toRecipient-container">
        <label class="toRecipient">TO:</label>
        <input class="toRecipient" type="text" size="45">
      </div>
        <br>
      <div id="checkbox-container" class="checkbox-container">
        <label for="newClient">New Client
        <input id="newClient" class="newInfo" type="checkbox" onclick="toggle()"></label>
        <label for="newBilling" style="padding-left: 20px;">New Billing
        <input id="newBilling" class="newInfo" type="checkbox"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="billingDetails-container" class="billingDetails-container">
      <div class="billingDetails">
          <label>Billing Contact:</label>
          <input class="billingContact" type="text" size="45">
          <label>Billing Phone:</label>
          <input class="billingPhone" type="text" size="45">
        <div>
          <label>Billing Address:</label>
          <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="Street Address" size="45">
          <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="City" size="45">
          <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="State" size="45">
          <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" size="45">
        </div>
        <label>Billing Email:</label>
        <input class="billingEmail" type="text" size="45">
      </div>
    </div>
```

And my JS:

```
    Template.InvoicePage.onCreated(function () {
  this.state = new ReactiveVar();
});

Template.InvoicePage.helpers({
  toggle: ()=>{
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("newClient");
    var displayBlock = document.getElementById("billingDetails-container");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      displayBlock.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      displayBlock.style.display = "none";
    }
  },
});

Template.InvoicePage.events({
  'change #newClient'(event, instance) {
    instance.state.set('newClient', event.target.checked)
  },
});
```

When I check the box, I get an error that 'toggle' is undefined. Should this be a template event instead of a helper? What am I missing?

Comment: Please also add the `Template.InvoicePage.onCreated` and `Template.invoicepage.events` code to the question (please not as comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done anything with meteor. There is a lot of different frameworks listed on the website. I'm not sure which one you use (if any). You can't possibly use angular, react and vuejs all at the same time.

Unless I'm wrong and there is a particular reason for the whole

```
Template.InvoicePage.helpers({...});
```

simply do

```
function toggle() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("newClient");
    var displayBlock = document.getElementById("billingDetails-container");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        displayBlock.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        displayBlock.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

It has nothing to do with a framework. Just vanilla javascript and html.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to show the `billingDetails-container` when the user selects the `New-Client` check-box. If that is correct, the below should work

> HTML

```
<div class="recipient">
  <div class="toRecipient-container">
    <label class="toRecipient">TO:</label>
    <input class="toRecipient" type="text" size="45">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="checkbox-container" class="checkbox-container">
    <label for="newClient">New Client
    <input id="newClient" class="newInfo" type="checkbox"></label>
    <label for="newBilling" style="padding-left: 20px;">New Billing
    <input id="newBilling" class="newInfo" type="checkbox"></label>
  </div>
</div>
{{#if showBillingDetails}}
  <div id="billingDetails-container" class="billingDetails-container">
    <div class="billingDetails">
      <label>Billing Contact:</label>
      <input class="billingContact" type="text" size="45">
      <label>Billing Phone:</label>
      <input class="billingPhone" type="text" size="45">
      <div>
        <label>Billing Address:</label>
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="Street Address" size="45">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="City" size="45">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="State" size="45">
        <input class="billingAddress" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" size="45">
      </div>
      <label>Billing Email:</label>
      <input class="billingEmail" type="text" size="45">
    </div>
  </div>
{{/if}}
```

> JS

```
Template.InvoicePage.events({
  'change #newClient'(event, instance) {
    instance.state.set({
      'newClient': event.target.checked  //Here, we are set the newclient property of state object based on client's selection.
    });
  }
});

Template.InvoicePage.helpers({
  showBillingDetails() {
    const state = Template.instance().state.get();
    return state && state.newClient; //Here, we use the newclient property of state to decide whether or not to display the billingDetails-container
  }
});
```

Comment: I wish I could say that it worked, but now the billingDetails-container will not display at all. Even if I remove the "display: none" in the css.

Comment: Do you still have the `newClient` reactive-var in the `onCreated` function? If not, please add it as well. Is there any error when you click on the 'New Client' checkbox?

Comment: The onCreated function I have is the one that is posted in the original question. Nothing happens when the checkbox is clicked; there are no errors.